# Converting JSON Array into Java Objects and attaching to ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, listview-adapter

I'm relatively new to Android development and I've been stuck on this for a couple of weeks.

I'm working with a JSON Array and I've been able to log that I am returning the JSON Array with an API call and that it is breaking up the array into separate JSON Objects.

```
Hero JSON {"PrimaryName":"Abathur","ImageURL":"Abathur","AttributeName":"Abat","Group":"Specialist","SubGroup":"Utility","Translations":"Abatur,АБАТУР,아바투르,阿巴瑟"}

Hero JSON {"PrimaryName":"Alarak","ImageURL":"Alarak","AttributeName":"Alar","Group":"Assassin","SubGroup":"Ambusher","Translations":"亞拉瑞克,阿拉纳克,알라라크,Аларак"}

etc...
```

From what it appears it is converting those JSON Objects into Java Objects.

```
hotsbuddy.HeroDataModel@f27ef8a
hotsbuddy.HeroDataModel@db939fb
etc...
```

When I changed the Log to return the Hero Name, Hero Image and Hero Group from my

```
public static HeroDataModel fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)
```

method I get this:

```
03-24 18:44:53.828 30539-30539/com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy D/HoTS: Hero Abathur Abathur Specialist
03-24 18:44:53.828 30539-30539/com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy D/HoTS: Hero Alarak Alarak Assassin
03-24 18:44:53.828 30539-30539/com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy D/HoTS: Hero Alexstrasza Alexstrasza Support
```

So I can see that I am getting Java Objects back.

These logs are being placed in my HeroDataModel class. However, I'm having an issue attaching these Java Objects to my ListView and ListView Adapter.

When I log my ArrayList creation in my API call I am getting Java Objects returned.

```
Array [com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy.HeroDataModel@f27ef8a, 
com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy.HeroDataModel@db939fb, etc...]
```

These objects are not showing up in App View. I'm not getting a list just a blank white background with the blue bar with my app name from the Main Layout.

I've been using these guides from CodePath but I'm just not quite able to finish off this feature.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#row-view-recycling
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Converting-JSON-to-Models#bonus-setting-up-your-adapter

I know I'm using a different type of Adapter but I was kind of following along from a couple simple apps I built from a Udemy course I completed.

Here is the API I'm working with:
https://api.hotslogs.com/Public/Data/Heroes

My GitHub repo:
https://github.com/tfreebern2/hotsbuddy

Here is my HeroDataModel code:

```
 public class HeroDataModel {

    private String mHeroName;
    private String mHeroImage;
    private String mHeroGroup;

    public String getHeroName() {
        return this.mHeroName;
    }

    public String getHeroImage() {
        return this.mHeroImage;
    }

    public String getHeroGroup() {
        return this.mHeroGroup;
    }


    public static HeroDataModel fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        HeroDataModel h = new HeroDataModel();

        try {

            h.mHeroName = jsonObject.getString("PrimaryName");
            h.mHeroImage = jsonObject.getString("ImageURL");
            h.mHeroGroup = jsonObject.getString("Group");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
        return h;

    }


public static ArrayList<HeroDataModel> fromJson(JSONArray    jsonObjects) {
        JSONObject heroJson;
        ArrayList<HeroDataModel> heroes = new ArrayList<HeroDataModel> .   ();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length(); i++) {
            try {
                heroJson = jsonObjects.getJSONObject(i);
//                Log.d("HotS", "Hero JSON " + heroJson);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }

            HeroDataModel hero = HeroDataModel.fromJson(heroJson);
//            Log.d("HoTS", "Hero " + hero);
            if (hero != null) {
                heroes.add(hero);
            }

        }
//        Log.d("HoTS", "Heroes Array" + heroes);
        return heroes;
    }

}
```

My HeroListAdapter:

```
public class HeroListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HeroDataModel> {

    public HeroListAdapter(HeroListActivity context, ArrayList<HeroDataModel> heroes) {
        super(context, 0, heroes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        HeroDataModel currentHero = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.hero_list_item, parent, false);
        }


        TextView heroNameView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.hero_name);

        TextView heroImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.hero_image);

        TextView heroGroupView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.hero_group);

        heroNameView.setText(currentHero.getHeroName());
        heroImageView.setText(currentHero.getHeroImage());
        heroGroupView.setText(currentHero.getHeroGroup());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

My HeroListActivity:

```
public class HeroListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String HEROES_URL = "https://api.hotslogs.com/Public/Data/Heroes";

    ArrayList<HeroDataModel> heroes;
    HeroListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hero_list);
        heroListAPI(HEROES_URL);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHeroes);
        heroes = new ArrayList<HeroDataModel>();
        adapter = new HeroListAdapter(this, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void heroListAPI(String url) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                ArrayList<HeroDataModel> heroes = HeroDataModel.fromJson(response);
                heroes.clear(); // clear existing items if needed
                heroes.addAll(HeroDataModel.fromJson(response)); // add new items
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONArray response) {
                Log.e("HoTS", "Fail " + e.toString());
                Log.d("HoTS", "Status code " + statusCode);
                Toast.makeText(HeroListActivity.this, "Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My Hero_List Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHeroes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Hero_List_Item Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.timfreebernii.hotsbuddy.HeroActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hero_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hero Name"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hero_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hero Image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hero_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hero Group"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "However, I'm having an issue attaching these Java Objects to my ListView and ListView Adapter" -- what is the issue?

Comment: You need to use Serializable class.

Comment: I'll add this to the main post but I'm getting nothing to show up in the view. No list. Just a blank layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson Library or retrofit to convert json objects into model class

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution with some help.

My HeroListActivity is where I was making the API call and trying to convert the Json into Java Objects.

Here I declared my adapter in the HeroListActivity class outside of my onCreate method and removed the declaration of the ArrayList. I created a new HeroListAdapter using 'this' and 'new' ArrayList() as parameters. Then I attached the adapter to my ListView.

```
public class HeroListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String HEROES_URL = "https://api.hotslogs.com/Public/Data/Heroes";

HeroListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hero_list);
    heroListAPI(HEROES_URL);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHeroes);
    adapter = new HeroListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<HeroDataModel>());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

... more code

}
```

In my onSuccess method I created an ArrayList named 'myHeroes' with my renamed fromJsonToModelList.

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            ArrayList<HeroDataModel> myHeroes = HeroDataModel.fromJsonToModelList(response);

            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(myHeroes);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

I clear the adapter of any previous data, add all objects to the adapter and notify the adapter of any changes.

Some of the changes were just refactoring suggestions.

Ultimately, I wasn't passing the data to my adapter correctly nor do I think creating it correctly in my onCreate method.